# How to export latest enviornement variable in cygwin

Tags: cygwin

How can I export (All) latest environmental variable in Cygwin ?

I initially has `JAVA_HOME = C:\Program File\jdk16021` then I upgrade to 1.7 and change the environment variable to `JAVA_HOME = C:\Program File\jdk17055\` but Cygwin is still showing `JAVA_HOME = C:\Program File\jdk16021`

Comment: don't you need to simply define it in your HOME_directory/.bashrc file ?

Comment: Ok so my question is how to update .bashrc file using command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit your `.bashrc` file, that file should be located in your Home directory.

So, under the folder c:/users/your_user_name , create or edit the file .bashrc

```
export JAVA_HOME="C:/Program File/jdk17055"
```